# Joining sequence and document in XQUERY

Tags: xquery

I want to join document and sequence in XQUERY.
I'am trying this code:

```
let $in_xml :=
 <ss>
  <s>
   <p>2016/2/18/11/protocol13818.xml</p>
   <n>service1_1</n>
   <d>2016-04-01</d>  
  </s> 
  <s>
   <p>2016/2/18/15/protocol13819.xml</p>
   <n>service_2</n>
   <d>2016-04-02</d>
  </s>     
 </ss>

for $a in /version,
    $i in $in_xml
where $a/fn:base-uri() = $i/s/p

return <a>{$a//id/value/text(),"    ", $i//n}</a>
```

And having this result:

```
<a>c2e9bb01-acc1-4a64-b39b-f30ef514c5ec    <n>service1_1</n>
  <n>service_2</n>
</a>
<a>50543b71-48b8-41f6-956e-b444c5ad0abe    <n>service1_1</n>
  <n>service_2</n>
</a>
```

Why sequence is not filtered?
I want, that result will be look like this:

```
<a>c2e9bb01-acc1-4a64-b39b-f30ef514c5ec    <n>service1_1</n>
</a>
<a>50543b71-48b8-41f6-956e-b444c5ad0abe    <n>service1_2</n>
</a>
```

How can i do this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$i in $in_xml`, you iterate over every element in `$in_xml`, which is just `$in_xml` itself, since it is an element and not a sequence. To iterate over all the children of `$in_xml`, you need to select them:

You want something like

```
for $a in /version,
    $i in $in_xml/s
where $a/fn:base-uri() = $i/p

return <a>{$a//id/value/text(),"    ", $i/n}</a>
```

Comment: May be you know how to wrap result? <x><a></a><a></a></x>

Comment: You surround everything with `<x>{    }</x>`, like you surrounded the text with `<a>`. It can be arbitrary nested

Comment: I tryed this, and getted <x><a></a></x><x><a></a></x>. return count($r) - result is two string 1 and 1

Comment: No, *everything*, not just the part after the return